# How to solve start event_scheduler failure

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem with event_scheduler.

First, I've tried to type:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';`

I get an error:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Then I checked **my.ini** and I didn't find any problem:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
port = 3306
basedir = "C:\Code\mysql"
datadir = "C:\Code\mysql\data"
max_connections=200
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
secure_file_priv=C:\Code\mysql\data event_scheduler = 1
[client]
default-character-set= utf8
```

I am trying to enter:

```
flush privileges;//query OK;

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;   //or 1 doesn't work;
```

And I still get **error 1290**

Comment: Please paste *my.ini* code here as a text.

Comment: [mysql] default-character-set=utf8 [mysqld] port = 3306 basedir = "C:\Code\mysql" datadir = "C:\Code\mysql\data" max_connections=200 character-set-server=utf8 default-storage-engine=INNODB secure_file_priv=C:\Code\mysql\data event_scheduler = 1 [client] default-character-set= utf8